# How to expose a WPF usercontrol thru COM

Tags: .net, wpf, com, powerbuilder

we have a WPF usercontrol and we need to use it from an only COM-aware language (Powerbuilder). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote an article on using .Net components in Powerbuilder.

[Using C# Visual controls in PB Classic](http://anvil-of-time.com/wordpress/powerbuilder/powerbuilder-using-c-visual-objects-in-pb-classic-applications/)